# Nuget packages on server

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

When using Visual Studio, Nuget package manager makes it super easy to install very many tools.

What I want to know from experts is whether this code will run when we push it to the server? If not, is there a way to put Nuget package manager on the server so that packages can be installed easily on server also.

Experts, please tell me how they have installed various package on server that they used via Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager on their local machine.

Comment: This isn't the best form of a question for StackOverflow. I imagine your question will get down voted for not asking about a specific technical error/issue, but instead asks for opinions and guidance, which is NOT what stack overflow is for.

Comment: The NuGet packages themselves wont be published to your server. NuGets primarily deliver dependencies, like .dlls.  When you publish your application to the server via Visual Studio, all your .dll assemblies will be published, including the ones provided to you via Nuget. If you have automatic builds and deployments setup, you can have those processes restore dependencies (.dll) using Nuget.exe during the build process.